# ISO 9660 Level 1 compliant directory names

Tags: filesystems, standards

I am confused about the exact limitations on folder names in an ISO 9660 (Level 1) compliant filesystem.  I read through the wikipedia page and it says:

> File names are limited to eight characters with a three-character extension, using upper case letters, numbers and underscore only. - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#Restrictions)

When it says 'File Names' does it really mean file or folder names?  if not then what are the restrictions on folder names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the original ISO 9660 standard and its 1987 revision from [Ecma International](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-119.htm).  The precise text is

> 10.1 *Level 1*
>
> At Level 1 the following restrictions shall apply:
>
> - Each file shall consist of only one File Section;
> - a File Name shall not contain more than 8 [characters];
> - a File Name Extension shall not contain more than 3 [characters];
> - a Directory Identifier shall not contain more than 8 [characters].

(I've elided the distinction between "d-characters" and "d1-characters" which is irrelevant here.)

So the answer to your question is, at level 1, *file* names are restricted to 8+3 characters a la DOS, but *directory* ("folder") names are restricted to eight characters with no extension (unlike DOS, if I remember correctly).

Note that the standard has always included Level 2, which allows 31-character filenames (but still, if I'm reading it right, with only one dot); Level 1 is only for interop with pre-VFAT DOS, and shouldn't be necessary in a CDROM mastered today.  (The restrictions on the size and depth of a CDROM directory hierarchy are, unfortunately, still relevant.)

Comment: Yeah, it really shouldn't be neccesary, unfortunately ISO9660 Level 1 compliance is a requirement for standardized medical document exchange (IHE_XDM standard).   So although no one actually requires level 1 compliance in reality... i still have to do it :(  thanks for your help!